# Trying to insert data into SQL Server database using asp.net web application, getting an error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio to create an asp.net web application in C# and am having issues trying to insert data from one of my pages into a table in a SQL Server database. I am getting the following error message:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

My code looks like this;

[Block of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwfmO.png)

I have tried a few different things but I keep getting the same error and I've been on here and youtube for nearly an hour now and I can't find anything that relates to my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: I should add that I got this code from youtube and in the video, it worked fine. The only real difference is that my version is within an 'if' statement. I commented the if statement out and received the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is wrong. First, your sql query is incomplete; you need to include the actual variable names as part of your INSERT script:

```
INSERT INTO parent(parentID) VALUES (@parentID)
```

Then in your C# code, you need to include the exact name of the parameter when adding it to the collection:

```
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
```

This is obviously for one parameter, you'll need to repeat the same pattern for the rest. [Read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: One more question, for one of the entries in another part of the app, I need to be able to include DOB, which I have as 3 drop downs. How do I take the 3 different values and insert them into 1 (@dob) table field in my database? Cheers.

Comment: That's a different question, but if you column type is datetime, create a DateTime object from the values in C# and insert them to the database.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...